# How to make year scale bar unit in figtree software?

Tags: sequence-alignment, visualization, phylogenetics

I have generated phylogenetic trees for virus sequences by using beast software.

I observed in various research articles that the phylogentic trees also have a scale-bar (which mostly represents residue substitution per site). When I visualized the generated trees in FigTree v1.4.3, the scale bar unit (number) seems to be in thousands! While mostly the scale bar represents 0.1 or 0.5 such numbers.

I intend to add a scale bar to my year scale bar to phylogenetic tree, please advice me how to generate the optimal scale and value in accordance with the graphs.

Comment: Could you add a link to your current image to see what is some problem? But the problem is that you need to modify the scale of a bar or add a new one?

Comment: The scale bar is scaled to the range of the branch lengths in your tree file. If the branch lengths are in units of years but you want to show substitutions per site in the scale bar, you'll need to produce a tree file with branch lengths in units of substitutions per site.

Comment: In figtree time scale is showing in reverse order how to resolve this problem?https://ibb.co/j9WRke                          i attach link with this comments

Comment: In FigTree v1.4.3 there is some bug when i reverse time scale bar it didn't work....In  this version FigTree v.1.4.2 it working fine.